# Cannot connect to VirtualBox VM from Kubuntu Host using NAT

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kubuntu, kde

Im using Kubuntu 13 as host and Xubuntu 12 as guest. In VM network options I have NAT selected, and port forwarding options like `127.0.0.1:23 => 10.0.2.15:22`. I can access Internet from guest, but when Im trying to connect via SSH to guest I get `connection refused`. Recently I used this setup on Windows 7 with success - no idea why it cant work on Ubuntu. 
Kindly help! :)

Comment: Can you try to forward a high port (greater than 1025)?

Comment: @EricCarvalho Remmaped ssh to 2222 instead of 23 - and it worked! Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ports < 1024 are privileged, only root can bind to them. As VirtualBox runs under an unprivileged user (the user you logged in with) it simply can't open a privileged port.

References:

1. [Why are ports below 1024 privileged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10182798/1898852)
2. [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to “privileged” ports (<1024) on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413807/1898852)